# Turn off "Approve with Apple Watch" macOS security alerts

Tags: security, password, apple-watch, big-sur, login-screen

Using macOS 11 Big Sur, many items that used to require my user password now annoyingly buzz my wrist.

I can still type my password, but now I have to first press "Use Password..." in the alert.

How can I disable this Apple Watch feature and make password entry the default method?

I do *not* want to disable unlocking the Mac itself from the login screen. There, I want to continue to use my Apple Watch.

[image: Approve with Apple Watch]

> System Preferences is trying to unlock the Software Update preferences.
>
> Approve with Apple Watch or enter your password to allow this.
>
> Use Password...

On the Apple Watch the prompt is:

> Double Click to Approve

Answer (score 1):

Go to `System Preferences` > `Security & Privacy` > `General`. Then disable the checkbox in the image below:

[image: settingsimage]

Comment: Is there any way to disable this for apps, but still allow unlocking the Mac itself?

Comment: @pkamb As of now I don't believe that's possible.